# Order of finite unitary group

Tags: finite-groups, finite-fields

This may be an easy exercise but I am not getting it. Let $\mathbf F_q$ be a finite field with $q$ elements and $\mathbf F_{q^2}$ be its degree two extension. Define an automorphism $\sigma$ of $\mathbf F_{q^2}$ by $\sigma (x) = x^q$. For any matrix $A = (a_{ij}) \in M_n(\mathbf F_{q^2})$, let $A^{\star} = (a_{ji}^{\sigma})$ (i.e., $A^{\star} = A^{\sigma \mathrm{t}}$). Then finite  unitary group $U_n(q)$ is a given by

$ U_n(q) = \left\lbrace A \in GL_n(\mathbf F_{q^2}) | A A^{*} = I_{n} \right\rbrace $

In a paper of [Wall (page 33)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=150210), it is mentioned that the order of this group is $q^{(n^2-n)/2} \prod\limits_{i=1}^{n} (q^i - (-1)^i)$.

> How to prove this?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @Pooja: I have replaced your link to the cached pdf file with the more stable link http://ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=150210 instead. You can get such links by clicking on "Make Link" in the Math Review page. 

Comment: Well, have you tried induction?

Comment: There's a "classical" formula of Steinberg for order of $G(k)$ for any conn'd ss group $G$ over finite field $k$: see 11.16 in his "Endomorphisms of linear alg. gps". Steinberg imposes extra hypotheses on $G$, but unnecessary, as explained in 1.6 in Oesterle's paper "Nombres de Tamagawa" (which gives an elegant description of the formula). The inputs in formula are dimension of $G$, size of $k$, action of geometric Weyl group on geometric character gp of max. $k$-torus $T$, and Frob. action on this char. gp. There's a shorter cohomological proof. 

Comment: I am getting n=1  case. But not n=2. I think that will help me to see general induction proof.

Comment: A good reference for elementary proofs of such results is Wan Zhexian, *Geometry of Classical Groups over Finite Fields*, second ed., Science Press, Beijing/New York, 2002.

Comment: @Anweshi Thanks a lot
@BCnrd, @Stanley Thanks for your references. But I don't have access to both neither Steinberg's paper nor to Wan Zhexian's book :(

Comment: The question is really just a *reference-request* (for an old, standard result).  The unified Lie-theoretic viewpoint is best, but there are nice older treatments such as Emil Artin's "The orders of the classical simple groups", Comm. Pure Appl. Math. 8 (1955).  That was the year of Chevalley's famous Tohoku paper, to which Artin alludes.  Calculating such orders of finite linear groups is not a trivial exercise, since it requires a strategy, but is by now fairly elementary.

Comment: Jim, do you know of a published proof of Steinberg's general formula other than his 1968 book?  More specifically, M. Boyarchenko showed me a proof using etale cohomology, and I wonder if an argument along those lines already appears in the literature (such as in some of the various papers which discuss $\ell$-adic cohomology of connected semisimple groups).  

Comment: See Peter Cameron's notes on classical groups: 
http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~pjc/class_gps/ .

Comment: @BCnrd: I think Steinberg's 1968 paper was the first to streamline the older Chevalley approach adapted separately by him and others for twisted ADE, Suzuki, Ree groups (Bruhat decomposition, Weyl group identities).  Lusztig brought more topological background to his 1976 Annals paper with Deligne which emphasizes Lefschetz fixed point methods in etale cohomology.  But I don't recall now what got written down about computing the group orders in that setting.   Lusztig started in that direction while still at Warwick. 

Comment: (cont) To be specific about references, at the end of a section of SGA 4-1/2 written by Deligne (Lecture Notes 569, p. 230), a geometric approach to Steinberg's uniform order formula is sketched.   The ideas are worked out in more detail in MR685938 (84g:20086),
Springer, T. A.,
The order of a finite group of Lie type.
Algebraists’ homage: papers in ring theory and related topics (New Haven, Conn., 1981), pp.
81–89, Contemp. Math., 13, Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, R.I., 1982.


Comment: Advice:  These further comments on unified proofs of the most general order formula are not directly an answer about finite unitary groups, but eventually it's the direction to go.   In the short run, if access is a problem, try one of the more classical sources mentioned already or if necessary online notes.    Don't spend a lot of time rediscovering proofs of such old theorems.   There are many things left to do in mathematics.

Comment: @Robin Thanks a lot for the reference. 
@Jim Thanks a lot for amazing advice. It is precious. 

Comment: @BCnrd Brian, would you have a reference for Boyarchenko's calculation using étale cohomology ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This question from 2010 was just listed as "active", apparently because someone (not myself) downvoted it today.  Anyway, rather than prolong the previous list of comments, I'll offer an explicit answer by pointing to an online resource that slightly predates Steinberg's 1968 AMS Memoir and is still a useful way to get into the details about Chevalley groups and their twisted analogues.   In 1967-68, Steinberg gave a course at Yale which was written up by listeners and published in mimeographed form by the math department there.   These typed notes are not as readable as typeset material and lack an index, but have been scanned in PDF format and placed on Steinberg's homepage at UCLA http://www.math.ucla.edu/~rst/

In particular, Section 11 deals with twisted groups, their Bruhat decompositions, and their orders.    One advantage of this broader approach via Chevalley groups is that it makes transparent the close analogy between the order formulas for finite unitary groups and for special linear groups of similar size.   In any case, as previous comments already indicate, the suggestion in the question that "This may be an easy exercise ..." is misguided.    But the order formula itself is standard and well studied from a variety of directions in the literature cited.

Comment: Do you know if Steinberg's web page (in particular, these scanned notes) is archived anywhere?

Comment: I'm aware that the page was taken down at some point, but I'm unaware of any archived source (though some people other than me have presumably kept a copy of the PDF file of his Yale lecture notes).   After Steinberg's death I heard that another effort would be made to arrange some kind of formal publication of the notes.   Even though most topics are included in other sources such as Carter's 1972 book or more recent texts, the Steinberg notes still offer a unique perspective on others.

Comment: P.S. I don't know what the current copyright status of Steinberg's lecture notes may be, but on checking my own notes I recall that at least one mathematician has created a LaTeX version of the original typed text.   (So there are certainly PDF files circulating.)

Comment: This is to let everyone know that these famous Yale notes of Steinberg are now available in the University Lecture Series published by the AMS, see https://bookstore.ams.org/ulect-66.

Comment: Note too that the Steinberg lectures are now tyoeset in LaTeX and well-edited in the AMS version,

Comment: The notes were archived! https://web.archive.org/web/20141024191617/http://www.math.ucla.edu/~rst/YaleNotes.pdf